# My granite foundation was underpinned and has load-bearing 6x6 posts around the perimeter of the basement. How to repoint behind them?

Tags: water, framing, foundation, masonry

My building has a granite block foundation supporting a brick structure above it.

In the 80's, the building was gutted and the foundation was underpinned. They added load bearing posts around the perimeter of the basement that are supporting the joists and all the framing above. The granite block holds up the brick, the posts hold up the framing. It's like building inside of a building.

It's about time to repoint, water has started seeping (pouring) in.

There's actually a leak between some of the granite blocks in a corner of the building, but access is totally blocked by the 6x6. The posts in the corner are almost like a post and beam style construction, they're cut to fit around the framing, so I don't want to remove it completely since it's serving as a hanger too.

My first thought is to build a temporary load bearing wall perpendicular to the joists to hold the load, then cut the post at the top and bottom, do the best job possible in repointing, and reinstall new wood between the old cuts. But if everything isn't perfectly square, things are going to settle weird, and I'm worried that any shift at all might cause the outer bricks to crack. I'm sure the walls above are helping hold the bricks straight.

I'm considering replacing it with a lally column so I can cut it precisely and make it removable for the future access. Maybe even considering using the screw type column. There is a bottom plate to attach it to.

TL;DR: There's a 6x6 post blocking access to repoint, and it's leaking. How do you do it?